# Can OWA be tricked into enhanced mode using Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, outlook-web-access

I'm using a CR-48 and am trying to access OWA (at least until Remoting starts working) and am having a hard time dealing with mail.

Are there extensions or tricks (besides IE tab) that will work?

Comment: IE tab won't work on Cr-48 anyways.

Comment: What exactly are the problems you're facing? I'm using OWA with the Chrome browser on both Windows and Ubuntu, and it works ok. Only problem I had was with non-English texts being displayed as question marks, which was solved by changing the default language. I'm not doing more than the basic actions, so problems might be hiding deeper.

Comment: The main problem so far is I can't get to my search folders.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. OWA relies on Internet Explorer specific functions. If you are not on Windows, these won't install.